Generate PDF in Woocommerce bulk action
I'm trying to generate a Pdf (DomPdf) through Woocommerce's bulk action. Before HPOS this seemed to work, but now it doesn't anymore.
The bulk action is added to the dropdown and the Admin-notice is shown when I execute the action.
$add_custom_download_action = function ( array $bulk_actions ) {
    return array_merge( $bulk_actions, [ 'custom_download_action' => 'Perform custom download action' ] );
};

$custom_download_action_handler = function ( string $redirect_to, string $action, array $post_ids ) {
    
    if ( $action !== 'custom_download_action' )
        return $redirect_to; // Exit

    require WPO_WCPDF()->plugin_path() . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();
    $dompdf->set_paper( 'letter' , 'landscape' );
    $dompdf->loadHtml($content); //this variable is build up as an html string
    $dompdf->render();  
    $dompdf->stream('orders.pdf',array("Attachment"=>0));
    
    return add_query_arg( 'bulk_action', 'custom-download-action-notice', $redirect_to );
};

$custom_download_action_notice = function () {
    if ( isset( $_GET['bulk_action'] ) && 'custom-download-action-notice' === $_GET['bulk_action'] ) {
        print '<div class="updated" style="border-left-color: #d7f"><p>PDF downloaded</p></div>';
    }
};

add_filter( 'bulk_actions-woocommerce_page_wc-orders', $add_custom_download_action);
add_filter( 'handle_bulk_actions-woocommerce_page_wc-orders', $custom_download_action_handler, 10, 3 );
add_action( 'admin_notices', $custom_download_action_notice );


Are you sure it seemed to work? Please also read: What Do You Mean "It Doesn't Work"? What makes you think HPOS is the cause?

@KIKOSoftware, thanks for the reply. You're right I should have been more clear. Before the upgrade to HPOS I've been able to get this script to download the PDF when the bulk action is triggered.
After the upgrade I updated the script to the new hooks. The code is executed and the Notice is shown, but the PDF is not downloaded anymore.

I've found the solution.
Since the redirect is still in place the actual data is never outputted. When I exit(0) after the stream, then the PDF is outputted.
